# Easiest way to format table for interactive tooltip for ggiraph

Tags: r, ggiraph

I have this basic example below. As you will see it is an interactive plot. What I am hoping to achieve at the moment is to take the `dummy_data` and make it a formatted table for the tooltip when you hover over a datapoint. I am going to have different sets for points but **I just want this one example to work for all** and then I can change the data.

As you will see in the `tooltip =`  argument it would need to be included there. I am just not sure if there is an easy way to pass this table as it is printed in there with some css to format it easily. I want it to look as good or better than `dummy_data` printed to console essentially.

I hope this is clear enough? Please let me know if I can clarify. See reprex below.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)
#> Warning: package 'ggiraph' was built under R version 4.1.2


dataset <- mtcars

dummy_data <- 
  data.frame(
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
    Feature = c("FeatureA","FeatureB",
                "FeatureC","FeatureD","FeatureE","FeatureF","FeatureG",
                "FeatureH","FeatureI","FeatureJ","FeatureK","FeatureL",
                "FeatureM","FeatureN","FeatureO","FeatureP","FeatureQ",
                "FeatureR","FeatureS","FeatureT","FeatureU"),
    Rating = c(1L,1L,1L,1L,3L,3L,4L,1L,
               4L,1L,4L,1L,1L,1L,1L,4L,1L,1L,2L,3L,2L)
  )

dummy_data
#>     Feature Rating
#> 1  FeatureA      1
#> 2  FeatureB      1
#> 3  FeatureC      1
#> 4  FeatureD      1
#> 5  FeatureE      3
#> 6  FeatureF      3
#> 7  FeatureG      4
#> 8  FeatureH      1
#> 9  FeatureI      4
#> 10 FeatureJ      1
#> 11 FeatureK      4
#> 12 FeatureL      1
#> 13 FeatureM      1
#> 14 FeatureN      1
#> 15 FeatureO      1
#> 16 FeatureP      4
#> 17 FeatureQ      1
#> 18 FeatureR      1
#> 19 FeatureS      2
#> 20 FeatureT      3
#> 21 FeatureU      2

dataset$carname <- row.names(dataset)
dataset$tooltip <- paste(dummy_data)



gg_scatter <- ggplot(dataset, 
                     aes(x = disp, y = qsec, tooltip = 
                           paste0(
                             "<div class='header' checked>
                           <p>Ready to take ",tooltip,"? If so</p>
                           <a href='shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial'>Click Here!</a>
                           </div>"), 
                         data_id = carname, color= wt) ) + 
  geom_point_interactive(size=3) + 
  labs(title = "mouse over points") + 
  theme_minimal() + theme(
    plot.background = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank()
  )



girafe(ggobj = gg_scatter, 
       options = list(
         opts_sizing(rescale = TRUE, width = .7) )
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: So you want a better formatted table when hovering over the points?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I am not sure how best to coerce it so it will work well. I am hoping there is some way to pass the table into some loop to format it that the tooltip will work correctly or some other way to wrap it that it will work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass HTML code to the tooltip, so one way would be to create an HTML version of your table using `knitr::kable`, get the HTML table code and add it to your dataframe and then use as tooltip.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)

dataset <- mtcars

# add tooltip, using only first 10 rows to avoid showing too much text
dataset$tooltip <- knitr::kable(dummy_data[1:10, ], format = "html")

gg_scatter <- ggplot(dataset, 
                     aes(x = disp, y = qsec, 
                         tooltip = tooltip, color= wt) ) + 
    geom_point_interactive(size=3) 

girafe(ggobj = gg_scatter)
```

[image: output]

For more customisation for the tooltip table, instead of `knitr::kable`, you can use some other package that allows creating more customised HTML tables.

Comment: This is a great solution and kable has so many formatting options. Thanks so much!